# Why do Indonesians forbid green?

Tags: color, country

I've recently discovered that in Indonesia green is forbidden. But I cannot find the reason. Can anybody help please because I'm just wondering that, when put into context, when green is and is not allowed so that me as a tourist does not become offensive (If I visit Indonesia)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about UX. It is better suited at https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be for a couple of reasons:

- Green is in some countries with dense jungles (especially in south america) is considered a colour of death.
- 87% of Indonesia is Muslim, green is distinctly related to Islam and courtrooms. Bahasa Indonesia, the verb “memejahijaukan,” which literally means to take someone to the “green table,” as in taking someone to court.

This is what ive got from reading around.

See:

- https://blogs.transparent.com/indonesian/colors-in-indonesian-culture/
- http://www.colorguides.net/color_culture.html